# How to catch the string which contains the highest number?

Tags: bash

I have a variable which looks like that:

```
asgname='Company-DEV-API-65-ServerAutoScalingGroup-122MJNZLAAKW4 Company-DEV-API-68-ServerAutoScalingGroup-1SFNH4CSKKWA4'
```

I want to update the most current AutoScaling Group, which is in this case 68.

The asg names are separated by a space.

How can I catch the full asg name which contains the higher number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash and GNU sort:

```
tr ' ' '\n' <<< $asgname | sort -V | tail -n 1
```

Output:

```
Company-DEV-API-68-ServerAutoScalingGroup-1SFNH4CSKKWA4
```

I assume that all strings start with `Company-DEV-API-`.

Answer (score 0):

awk to help here.

```
echo "$asgname" | awk -F"-" '{len=$4>len?$4:(len?len:$4)} END{print len}'
```

Output will be `68`.

***Explanation:*** Printing the variable named `asgname` with `"`(double quotes) on it. Now using `|`(pipe) to send it's standard output as standard input to `awk` command. In `awk` command I am making field separator as `-`(dash). inside `awk`'s main body structure I am creating a variable len whose value will be $4(where you have number) now each time it's value will be compared to it's own value and it will replace it's own value if it's value is lesser than current $4's value. So finally we will get the HIGHEST value of it at last. So In END section of awk printing the value of variable len.

***EDIT:*** Just saw edit of your question. In case your variable is having space in it then you could do a minor change into above code and could get the desired results as follows too.

```
echo "$asgname" | awk -v RS=" " -F"-" '{len=$4>len?$4:(len?len:$4)} END{print len}'
```